# macOS suddenly exhibits weird mouse acceleration after idling

Tags: mouse, macos

Not sure what changed in the system but I'm running 10.15.6 (19G2021) and suddenly it have the mouse acceleration really fast if the system is idle for a few minutes.

As soon as I move the mouse for 1 second, the acceleration does return to normal.

I have a custom acceleration set in this system like this

```
defaults read .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling 0.125
```

Not sure if that matters.

I also have a Logitech mouse that is controlled by their software GHub.

Comment: If you have a standard wired USB mouse, give that a try to troubleshoot. Does the acceleration still happen? Have you tried resetting the com.apple.mouse.scaling to the expected, default value? (I don't know what that value is, btw.)

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues with a Logitech MX2 & Logi Options.
My bet is the Logi controller that 'forgets' what it's doing.

Tests would include:-

- uninstalling their drivers & see if the same happens without;
- test a different mouse;
- see if your G-series can be used fully with something like SteerMouse or USB Overdrive.

Comment: which one ultimately fixed it for you? (even though it might different for me)

Comment: Eventually Logi provided an update that stopped doing it… but mine uses Logi Options not the G-series control panel.